# Zend_Validate_EmailAddress versus filter_var(..., FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)

Tags: php, zend-framework, email-validation, zend-validate, filter-var

Of `Zend_Validate_EmailAddress` and `filter_var(..., FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`, which is better when validating an email address and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both can be used to validate an email address, but [`Zend_Validate_EmailAddress`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html#zend.validate.set.email_address) is more powerful. While filter_var is a simple yes or no validator, there are many options which can change how strict Zend_Validate_EmailAddress is.

You can choose which parts to validate, rules for validating those parts, and even to validate MX records.

Finally, Zend_Validate_EmailAddress can be readily used in combination with [`Zend_Filter_Input`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.filter.input.html) and [`Zend_Form`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.validators) where filter_var can't.